# Modifying Mozilla Thunderbird-68 buttons with userChrome.css

Tags: css, mozilla, thunderbird, userchrome.css

Since the [CustomizeMyBird](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomizeMyBird) plugin is no longer supported in Mozilla Thunderbird 68, my question is how to manually modify these buttons:

New Thunderbird 68 - **bad**:

[image]

Old Thunderbird 60 with Classic Toolbar Restorer - **good**:

[image]

I have enabled `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets true`, so now can change for example Menu bar background with `./chrome/userChrome.css` file:

```
menubar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The result:

[image]

How to get access to those buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the solution follows by using the code from [Aris-t2/customizeMyBird](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomizeMyBird/blob/master/xpi/content/css/tb_icons_tb3.css) :)

`userChrome.css` file contents:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

.hdrReplyToSenderButton,
.hdrDummyReplyButton,
.hdrReplyButton,
.hdrReplyAllButton,
.hdrReplyListButton,
.hdrFollowupButton,
.hdrForwardButton,
.hdrArchiveButton,
.hdrJunkButton,
.hdrTrashButton,
.hdrTagButton,
#button-getmsg,
#button-newmsg ,
#button-address,
#button-reply,
#button-replyall,
#button-replylist,
#button-forward,
.delete-button,
.junk-button,
#button-print,
#button-stop,
#button-file,
#button-nextUnread ,
#button-previousUnread,
#button-mark,
#button-tag,
#button-goback,
#button-goforward,
#button-compact,
#button-archive,
#button-chat,
#button-nextMsg,
#button-previousMsg,
.button-appmenu,
#qfb-show-filter-bar,
#palette-box #qfb-show-filter-bar{
    list-style-image: url("images/tb_mail_tb3.png") !important;
}

#button-send,
#button-contacts,
#spellingButton,
#button-attach,
#button-security,
#button-save,
#quoteButton,
#cut-button,
#copy-button,
#paste-button/*,
#attachmentNotificationBox > notification .messageImage*/ {
    list-style-image: url("images/tb_compose_tb3.png") !important;
}

/* main window */
.hdrReplyToSenderButton,
.hdrDummyReplyButton,
.hdrReplyButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 72px, 18px, 54px) !important;
}
.hdrReplyAllButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 90px, 18px, 72px) !important;
}
.hdrReplyListButton,
.hdrFollowupButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 126px, 18px, 108px) !important;
}
.hdrForwardButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 108px, 18px, 90px) !important;
}
.hdrArchiveButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 360px, 18px, 342px) !important;
}
.hdrJunkButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 162px, 18px, 144px) !important;
}
.hdrTrashButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 144px, 18px, 126px) !important;
}
.hdrTagButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 288px, 18px, 270px) !important;
}
#button-getmsg {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 18px, 18px, 0px) !important;
}
#button-newmsg {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 36px, 18px, 18px) !important;
}
#button-address {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 54px, 18px, 36px) !important;
}
#button-reply {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 72px, 18px, 54px) !important;
}
#button-replyall {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 90px, 18px, 72px) !important;
}
#button-replylist {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 126px, 18px, 108px) !important;
}
#button-forward {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 108px, 18px, 90px) !important;
}
.delete-button {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 144px, 18px, 126px) !important;
}
.junk-button {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 162px, 18px, 144px) !important;
}
#button-stop {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 198px, 18px, 180px) !important;
}
#button-file {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 216px, 18px, 198px) !important;
}
#button-nextUnread {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 234px, 18px, 216px) !important;
}
#button-previousUnread {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 252px, 18px, 234px) !important;
}
#button-mark {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 270px, 18px, 252px) !important;
}
#button-tag {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 288px, 18px, 270px) !important;
}
#button-goback {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 306px, 18px, 288px) !important;
}
#button-goforward {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 324px, 18px, 306px) !important;
}
#button-compact {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 342px, 18px, 324px) !important;
}
#button-archive {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 360px, 18px, 342px) !important;
}
#button-chat {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 396px, 18px, 378px) !important;
}
#button-nextMsg {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 414px, 18px, 396px) !important;
}
#button-previousMsg {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 432px, 18px, 414px) !important;
}
.button-appmenu {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 450px, 18px, 432px) !important;
    min-width: 35px !important;
}
#qfb-show-filter-bar,
#palette-box #qfb-show-filter-bar {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px, 378px, 18px, 360px) !important;
}

/* compose window */
#button-send {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 18px 18px 0px) !important;
}
#button-contacts {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 36px 18px 18px) !important;
}
#spellingButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 54px 18px 36px) !important;
}
#button-attach {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 72px 18px 54px) !important;
}
#button-security {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 90px 18px 72px) !important;
}
#button-save {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 108px 18px 90px) !important;
}
#quoteButton {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 126px 18px 108px) !important;
}
#cut-button {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 144px 18px 126px) !important;
}
#copy-button {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 162px 18px 144px) !important;
}
#paste-button {
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 180px 18px 162px) !important;
}
#button-print{
    -moz-image-region: rect(0px 180px 18px 162px) !important;
}

toolbar .toolbarbutton-1 .toolbarbutton-icon{
    height: 18px !important;
    width: 18px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

/*#attachmentNotificationBox > notification .messageImage {
  width: 18px !important;
  height: 18px !important;
  background-position: -54px top !important;
}*/

/* folder icons */
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Inbox"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Inbox),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Sent"] .tab-icon-image,  treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Sent),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Outbox"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Outbox),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Drafts"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Drafts),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Templates"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Templates),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Junk"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Junk),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Trash"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Trash),
.tabmail-tab[type="folder"][SpecialFolder="Archive"] .tab-icon-image, treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, specialFolder-Archive),
treechildren::-moz-tree-image(folderNameCol, imapShared-true) {
    list-style-image: url("images/tb_folder_tb3.png") !important;
}
```

Also folder "images" created under "chrome" directory, which should contain image files:

```
tb_compose_tb3.png
tb_folder_tb3.png
tb_mail_tb3.png
```

available at [Aris-t2/customizeMyBird/xpi/content/images/](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomizeMyBird/tree/master/xpi/content/images).

Now new Thunderbird looks nice and friendly again :) In addition - Thunderbird 68.0b5 (64-bit) supports TLSv1.3. Things getting better.